# TypeError: 'str' object not callable when asking for user input

Tags: string, function, input, module

```
def convert_to_kelvin(temperature, units): 
    temp = int(temperature)
    if units.upper() == 'K':
        return(None)

elif units.upper() == 'C':
    temp_K = temp + 273.15 
    return(temp_K)

elif units.upper() == 'F':
    temp_C = (5/9)*(temp - 32)
    temp_K = temp_C + 273.15 
    return(temp_K)

def is_gas(temperature): 
    tb = 373.13
    temp = int(temperature)
    if temp >= tb: 
        return(True)
    else:
        return(None)

def is_liquid(temperature): 
    tb = 373.13
    tm = 273.15
    temp = int(temperature)
    if temp > tm and temp < tb:
        return(True)
    else:
        return(None)

def is_solid(temperature): 
    tm = 273.15
    temp = int(temperature)
    if temp <= tm: 
        return(True)
    else:
        return(None)

unit_input = input("What units do you want?")
```

Creating a simple module program here, on this line:

```
unit_input = input("What units do you want?")
```

Keep getting a TypeError that says 'str' object is not callable. Don't get understand what is going on here, that line works perfectly find in a new python file that I opened, why isn't it working here?